# How can a high level mythic wizard “bond” items to be usable only by himself?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, wizard

My party has reached the end of our campaign and my level 20 mythic wizard has crafted a few things to help complete his "final form" so to speak. A ring, a cloak, and some legendary bracers. My question, is there a way to bond these items to my wizard without using arcane bond or any artifact abilities, since I have nothing left as far as mythic tier path abilities to upgrade them with?

I'm trying to bond them or at least find a way to enchant them to become essentially inert if I were to die.

The main reason I'm trying to cause my items to become inert after death is because my character might finish his storyline as a supremely evil and powerful character with a clone waiting on standby once his death comes to pass. I hope the items will then fail to work for anyone but my new clone once he retrieves the items.

I've been scouring d20PFSRD and haven't found anything that'd work properly. We tend to avoid 3rd party material.

Comment: More details are often better. It’s no good getting an answer that doesn’t work because of a detail that the answer-writer didn’t know about.

Answer (score 3):

## Make them [Cursed Items](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items/)

Under the various descriptions of cursed item effects, there's a [requirements](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic-items/cursed-items/#Requirement) section:

> Some items have stringent requirements that must be met for them to be usable. **To keep an item with this kind of curse functioning, one or more of the following conditions must be met.** [...]  **If the requirement is not met, the item ceases to function.**

Maybe the requirement for using them is that the user must be you, otherwise they won't work. Thus, they'd work for your clone as well (since your clone is also you), but no one else. Or maybe they require a specific quest that only you and the clone know of to activate them.

Comment: This actually would be fitting. I never considered a curse to be helpful in this way until that you pointed out the "requirements" function. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @TomBrinkman The only reason I remembered it was that I was searching up similar stuff about requirements for using items a couple weeks ago. No problem!